# Bicep file for role assignments in resourcelevel getting failed

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a bicep file as below to create role assignment to `resourceGroup` scope using azure devops pipeline.

main.bicep

```
    targetScope = 'resourceGroup' 
    
    @description('Principal type of the assignee.')
    @allowed([
      'Device'
      'ForeignGroup'
      'Group'
      'ServicePrincipal'
      'User'
    ])
    param principalType string
    
    @description('the id for the role defintion, to define what permission should be assigned')
    param RoleDefinitionId string
    
    @description('the id of the principal that would get the permission')
    param principalId string
    
    @description('the role deffinition is collected')
    resource roleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
      scope: subscription()
      name: RoleDefinitionId
    }
    
    resource RoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = [for id in split(principalId, ','): {
      name: guid(resourceGroup().id, RoleDefinitionId, id)
      properties: {
        roleDefinitionId: roleDefinition.id
        principalId: principalId
        principalType: principalType
      }
    }]


parameters file
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
     "principalType": {
         "value": "#{principalType}#"
     },
     "RoleDefinitionId": {
       "value": "#{RoleDefinitionId}#"          
     },     
     "principalId": {
       "value": "#{principalId}#"
     }
  } 
}
```

pipeline file.

```
      - rolesname: readerall
        environment: development      
        scope: resourcegroup
        principalType: Group     
        principalid: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccccccc,ddddddddddddddddddddd
        roleDefinitionId: acddxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        resourceGroup: aks-rg
   
      - rolesname: reader_apimrg_all
        environment: development      
        scope: resourcegroup
        principalType: Group     
        principalid: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccccccc,ddddddddddddddddddddd
        roleDefinitionId: acddxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        resourceGroup: apim-rg


      - rolesname: reader_lawrg_all
        environment: development      
        scope: resourcegroup
        principalType: Group     
        principalid: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccccccc,ddddddddddddddddddddd
        roleDefinitionId: acddxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        resourceGroup: la-rg
```

So Now I tried to ammend my templates to assign the Roles in resource level (looking to assign this to Appinsight). my new bicep file was below.. But its  failing completely..

```
@description('Principal type of the assignee.')
@allowed([
  'Device'
  'ForeignGroup'
  'Group'
  'ServicePrincipal'
  'User'
])
param principalType string

@description('the id for the role defintion, to define what permission should be assigned')
param RoleDefinitionId string

@description('the id of the principal that would get the permission')
param principalId string

@description('the id of the Resource that would get the RBAC assigned')
param ResourceId string

@description('the role deffinition is collected')
resource roleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: RoleDefinitionId
}

resource RoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = [for id in split(principalId, ','): {
  name: guid(ResourceId, RoleDefinitionId, id)
  scope: Insights
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinition.id
    principalId: id
    principalType: principalType
  }
}]
```

So looking for solutions on below requirements.

- can I re-use same initail Bicep file used ( the working for resourcegrop level)  to have the Role assignments in Resource level as well.
- Can I use the same scenario with any kind of resource, for example if I pass the type of resource and name of the resource as input, the RBAC should be assigned to that resource

Comment: `scope: Insights`, where do you define `Insights`?

Comment: yes, the scope is invalid and hence its failing. Looking for a way to pass resource id to the scope, so that we can use to anu resources

Comment: this is not supported, there is an experimental feature regarding that tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71851075/4167200

Comment: @Thomas Since Bicep seems litle complex for roleassignemnts in Resource level, I tried with ARM template as well. But faced issue again as given in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74037943/arm-template-deployment-error-for-appinsights-roleassignments