# ARM template deployment error for Appinsights roleassignments

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

We are using below ARM template for role assignement in Appinsights with ADO pipelines, where the template parameters are replacing from ADO pipelines paramters. This worked for one resource deployment and when we tried for multiple resources, ARM template deployment failing with below error.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "RoleDefinitionId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string"
        },        
        "AppInsightName": {
            "type": "string"
        } 

 },   

    "resources":[    
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('AppInsightName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid('AppInsightName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', parameters('RoleDefinitionId'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
      }
    }
 ]

}
```

Parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": { 
     "RoleDefinitionId": {
       "value": "#{roleDefinitionId}#"
     },
     "principalId": {
       "value": "#{principalId}#"
     },
     "AppInsightName": {
       "value": "#{appInsightName}#"
     } 
                          
  } 
}
```

Input to devops pipeline yaml

```
parameters:
  roleList:
  - rolesname: reader_Appinsight_group1
    environment: development
    principalType: Group     
    principalid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    roleDefinitionId: acdd72axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    appInsightName: myappinsight1
    resourceGroup: myappinsight1-rg

  - rolesname: reader_Appinsight_group2
    environment: development
    principalType: Group     
    principalid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    roleDefinitionId: acdd72axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    appInsightName: myappinsight1
    resourceGroup: myappinsight1-rg
```

ERROR:

```
 {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

Again I tried with multiple option for the role definition name to be unique, but got different errors

eg:

```
    "resources":[    
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id, parameters('RoleDefinitionId'), parameters('principalId'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', parameters('RoleDefinitionId'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
      }
    }
 ]

}
```

Error for the above
The template resource 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for type 'Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments' at line '18' and column '71' has incorrect segment lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a roleAssignment needs to be a function of the principal, role and scope.  Once a role exists for a given principal, role & scope under a given name, nothing can be changed on that role assignment.

In your template your roleAssignment name is just a function of the appInsights resource name, which means you can have exactly one of those roleAssignments.  Your `guid()` function in the name needs to be:

`guid(parameters('RoleDefinitionId'), parameters('principalId'), parameters('AppInsightName'))`

Note that you may have to remove some previously created roleAssignments (for the given principal, role and scope) if they were not created with the same naming algorithm before that template will successfully deploy.

Comment: I tried with       "name": "[concat(parameters('AppInsightName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid(resourceGroup().id, parameters('principalId')))]", , and seems working. Is this fine to proceed with n number of deployments for the role assignements?

Comment: That will work as long as you don't give that principal prems to another appInsights instance using the same template.  You also couldn't use that guid() seed for another resource type with the same principal.  So it will work within reason, but it's not as unique as the system requires. Using principal, role and scope is key to the seed.

Comment: @bmoore-msft I had a question regarding this approach, I get the guid() portion of this assignment will be same even if we run this for a different app insight resource, but should the concat with the app insight name make this unique enough ?

Asking this because I actually faced this issue, doing just concat does not make it unique because the assignment apparently only checks the guid part ?? I fixed it by adding the name to guid also, but just curious why this is so ? Couldn't find anything in docs.

Comment: Yes - the "name" of the roleAssignment is only the last segment of the concat (when you see concat in the examples above) - which in this example is just the guid() function.  You can "fix" these (usually) by adding something else to the guid() function params, you just need to be consistent _across the tenant_ in how you see the function otherwise it will be unmanageable.  Note that the sequence of the args in the function also matter.